# STL looping in reverse through map C++

Tags: c++, loops, dictionary, stl

```
const map<player, int>::iterator beginning = game->begin(); 
const map<player, int>::iterator inserted = game->find(player(x, y));
map<player, int>::iterator left = inserted;
while(left != beginning)
{
//some operations here
--left;
}
```

As you, see I want to loop through the map in reverse, accessing all the elements before the one i've just inserted. The problem is, with the construction above it doesn't access the first element and I have no idea why. Any suggeestions? Is game->begin() the first element? If so, how to solve it?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't access"? Here, when `left == beginning` you do not enter the `while` cycle so obviously it does not get processed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will access all the elements before the one just inserted (not including the one just inserted).  It also protects against the situation where there are no elements 'before' the inserted element:

```
if (left != beginning) { 
    do {
        --left;
        //some operations here
    } while (left != beginning);
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but when i run the program: "Expression: map/set iterator not dereferencable"

Comment: Yeah - this isn't robust in the face of `game->find(player(x, y))` returning the element at the beginning. I made a small change to make it so.

Answer (score 3):

`game.begin()` is iterator to the first element.

you can start from the end of map by assigning the iterator to `rbegin`

```
map<player, int>::reverse_iterator it = game.rbegin()

for (it = game.rbegin(); it != game.rend(); it++)
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is working, but i really need to start form just inserted one, because the map is pretty big and it's time-consuming to loop all the elements starting from the end.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rbegin()` and `rend()`.

See here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/rbegin/ .

Answer (score 1):

The condition in the loop is wrong. You are asking to skip the loop when the iterator is `begin`, but you actually want to execute it in that case.

There are different things that you can do, the one that will cause the lesser impact in your code is probably going to be changing the loop to be infinite and adding the exit condition before changing the iterator:

```
while (true) {
   // do something
   if (it == begin()) break;
   --it;
}
```

Alternatively you can use reverse iterators (which you can initialize with your current iterator) and test against `rend()`.